# How to get execution_date as epoch time?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

In regular python code I can do:

```
import time
int(time.time())
```

This gives me the time as epoch.
I want to be able to do this with airflow macro: `execution_date`

This is what I tried:

```
"{{  strptime(execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') }}"
```

But this gives:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'strptime' is undefined

I'm running Airflow 1.9 & Python 2.7

Comment: You should do the datetime conversion in the Python code first and store it's value in a variable and then render the variable in the Jinja template

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#custom-filters) on custom filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Airflow 1.10, Airflow uses Pendulum for datetimes, which has attributes `timestamp()`, `int_timestamp` and `float_timestamp` which return the epoch.

So, you could do:

```py
{{ execution_date.int_timestamp }}
```

Docs: https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#attributes-and-properties

Other options are:

```py
{{ execution_date.strftime('%s') }} # Also Python 2
{{ execution_date.timestamp() }}    # Python >=3.3
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches to solving this, but first, you should simplify how you are accessing the timestamp.

As you are using Airflow, where execution_date is a [pendulum.Pendulum](https://airflow.apache.org/macros.html) object, you have access to the [execution_date.int_timestamp](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#attributes-and-properties) property.

In a more general situation assuming you are using Python 3.3+ there is a simpler way to get the epoch timestamp using the [timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method on a datetime object (which is also available on a Pendulum object).

```
execution_date.int_timestamp
Output => 1555477775

Python 3.3+:
int(execution_date.timestamp())
Output => 1555477775

Python 2.7+:
int(v.strftime('%s'))
Output => 1555477775
```

### 1. Direct formatting within the template

This method uses the timestamp() method of the datetime object to generate a float which then run through the built-in [int](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters) [filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#filters) of the Jinja2 template.

```
For Pendulum:
{{ execution_date.int_timestamp }}

For general datetime objects:
{{ execution_date.timestamp()|int }}
```

### 2. Create a custom Jinja2 Filter

If you are using this transformation in multiple places throughout your templates, it is probably worth creating a filter to centralise this.  With Airflow, you can [register a custom filter](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) on the DAG object.

```
import time

def epoch_int(v):
    return int(v.strftime('%s'))

dag = DAG(
  ...
  user_defined_filters={
    "epoch_int": epoch_int,
  }
  ...
)
```

and then use it in your template.

```
{{ execution_date|epoch_int }}
```

Comment: The 1st I can't do because I'm running Airflow 1.9 which doesn't have Pendulum. for the 2nd I get: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: Edited solution 2 for python 2.7 compatibilty

Comment: Your python 2 answer is waaaay more complicated than it needs to be `int(time.strftime("%s"))`

Comment: Edited python 2.7 solution as per Ash's suggestion - thanks